# Using the ImageCaptureCore framework on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, frameworks, iphone-privateapi

I'm using the `ImageCaptureCore` framework to control a DSLR camera connected via USB in a Cocoa application. Now I'd like to do the same on iOS (camera connected to an iPad via a "Lightning to USB Camera Adapter") and wondered which framework to use.

I'm not going to submit the App to the AppStore, so using a private framework is totally fine. 
I searched for appropriate headers in [iOS-Runtime-Headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers), but only found `ImageCapture`. Any hint in the right direction is most welcome.

Comment: I don't believe there is such thing. If you have knowledge of the DSLR and it's MFI certified, you might be able to use ExternalAccessory framework. If the DSLR supports WiFi, you might be able to connect that way. Here's a link to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902140/create-hardware-for-iphone-to-connect-with-external-device-arduino ... Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 13.0+, the [ImageCaptureCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imagecapturecore) framework is available for use on iPadOS to

> - Discover connected cameras and scanners
> - View and modify the folders, files, and metadata on a connected    camera
> - Take photos directly on a connected camera using tethered capture
> - Perform overview scans and scans on a connected scanner

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no framework like ImageCaptureCore on the iOS platform available there are three options I think:

1. As stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908451/usb-programming-on-iphone) there may be the chance of talking to the device on low level. I don't know if there are any frameworks or standards that work for cameras or taking photos with cameras.
2. Depending on the camera you want to trigger there also might be the way of connecting your iPhone to the camera via cable to the trigger port of the DSLR. Specifications for the different manufacturer's specifications can be found [here](http://www.doc-diy.net/photo/remote_pinout/).
   However I think you don't want just to trigger the camera but to transfer the taken images.
3. You could use a SD Card with an integrated access-point to connect to and copy the image via a high level protocol.